# RabbitMQ queue count based on message header value

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am exploring the option of getting the queue count based on the custom header value in the message. For ex, If I have a queue that has 100 messages - 25 with a custom header "CUSTHDR" and value = "Apple", 25 with header value "Orange" and another 50 with header value "Grapes", I need to be able to get the count of messages in the queue based on the header value. Something like a method that returns 50 when I run GetMessageCount("Grapes");

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far

Comment: To be frank, I am still trying to know the options available for me (I just started off using RabbitMQ). One option I have is to use the MessageCount(string queueName) method in the IModel interface. But this method returns the totat message count by taking only the queue name (without any filtering condition). I am trying to reach out experienced developers to know if there is a better option.

Comment: @GouthamSomashekar Similar is my requirement. Did you find an alternative solution to this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by RabbitMQ.

You would have to consume all messages, group them by header to get counts, and then re-enqueue them (or reject the deliveries).